# Vs keeps taking old js {name}.js [Dynamic]

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, iis, knockout.js

I changed a js file that is being debugged in vs but IE does not take the new changes into the browser. I already removed the cache, restarted the pc, switched off the bundeling and minifier, restarted IIS. And now i am comming to a point not knowing how to fix it.

Comment: Did you update the filename in your HTML as well as the actual file name..?

Comment: it is not the name that changed, its the content of the JS that has been changed

Comment: I had the same problem, IIS is horrible in that respect, you never know what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Robert did you fixed it ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the file so IE thinks it's a new file or debuging with a different browser?